# Uneven data on x-axis and y-axis

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, scikit-learn

```
codePath = 'D:\\archive\\test\\'
num_mfcc_features = 64

english_mfcc = np.array([]).reshape(0, num_mfcc_features)
for file in glob.glob(codePath + 'temp_en/*.npy'):
    current_data = np.load(file).T
    english_mfcc = np.vstack((english_mfcc, current_data))

hindi_mfcc = np.array([]).reshape(0, num_mfcc_features)
for file in glob.glob(codePath + 'temp_hi/*.npy'):
    current_data = np.load(file).T
    hindi_mfcc = np.vstack((hindi_mfcc, current_data))

mandarin_mfcc = np.array([]).reshape(0, num_mfcc_features)
for file in glob.glob(codePath + 'temp_ma/*.npy'):
    current_data = np.load(file).T
    mandarin_mfcc = np.vstack((mandarin_mfcc, current_data))

# Sequence length is 10 seconds
sequence_length = 1000

list_english_mfcc = []
num_english_sequence = int(np.floor(len(english_mfcc)/sequence_length))
for i in range(num_english_sequence):
    list_english_mfcc.append(english_mfcc[sequence_length*i:sequence_length*(i+1)])
list_english_mfcc = np.array(list_english_mfcc)
english_labels = np.full((num_english_sequence, 1000, 3), np.array([1, 0, 0]))

list_hindi_mfcc = []
num_hindi_sequence = int(np.floor(len(hindi_mfcc)/sequence_length))
for i in range(num_hindi_sequence):
    list_hindi_mfcc.append(hindi_mfcc[sequence_length*i:sequence_length*(i+1)])
list_hindi_mfcc = np.array(list_hindi_mfcc)
hindi_labels = np.full((num_hindi_sequence, 1000, 3), np.array([0, 1, 0]))

list_mandarin_mfcc = []
num_mandarin_sequence = int(np.floor(len(mandarin_mfcc)/sequence_length))
for i in range(num_mandarin_sequence):
    list_mandarin_mfcc.append(mandarin_mfcc[sequence_length*i:sequence_length*(i+1)])
list_mandarin_mfcc = np.array(list_mandarin_mfcc)
mandarin_labels = np.full((num_mandarin_sequence, 1000, 3), np.array([0, 0, 1]))


del english_mfcc
del hindi_mfcc
del mandarin_mfcc

total_sequence_length = num_english_sequence + num_hindi_sequence + num_mandarin_sequence
Y_train = np.vstack((english_labels, hindi_labels))
Y_train = np.vstack((Y_train, mandarin_labels))

X_train = np.vstack((list_english_mfcc, list_hindi_mfcc))
X_train = np.vstack((X_train, list_mandarin_mfcc))


del list_english_mfcc
del list_hindi_mfcc
del list_mandarin_mfcc

X_train, X_val, Y_train, Y_val = train_test_split(X_train, Y_train, test_size=0.2)
```

This is giving me this error

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [3, 0]
```

I know `english_mfcc, hindi_mfcc, mandarin_mfcc` become zero because when they are out of for loop, now i cant figure out the way to put `num_english_sequence` inside loop and get desired results.

Comment: Not an answer to your question but you absolutely need to use functions. You do the same thing thrice because you have three languages. What if you had 100? The only thing that changes between languages is a file path and a tuple.

Comment: i had same thought once i figure out this problem i am going to change it to functions, btw thanks for advice :)